# how to modify copied text before pasting using javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

Im trying to write a function that runs when a persons tries to paste some text to (for example: a text area/editable div) the function should check if the text is greater then 10 character, if the text is the function should keep only the first 10 characters and paste them to the (text area/editable Div).

i have attempted to use the clipboard api to handle this, but i could not find a way to paste the modified text.

HTML

```
<div id='editableDiv' contenteditable='true'>Paste</div>
```

JS

```
function handlePaste (e) {
        var clipboardData, pastedData;

        // Get pasted data via clipboard API
    clipboardData = e.clipboardData || window.clipboardData;
    pastedData = clipboardData.getData('Text');

    //if pasted text is longer then 10 chars
       if (pastedData.length > 10) {
            console.log("its longer", pastedData.length);
            //we take only the first 10 chars
            var limitedData = pastedData.substring(0, 10);
   //  i want this text to be pasted
}

}

document.getElementById('editableDiv').addEventListener('paste', handlePaste);
```

JS FIDDLE 
https://jsfiddle.net/swL8ftLs/12/

im expecting the result to paste only the first characters to the div area

Answer (score 8):

You have to prevent the default action and instead insert the (modified) contents manually. [MDN's page on the `paste` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/paste_event) has an example (in this case, making the text upper case):

```js
// (From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/paste_event)

const target = document.querySelector('div.target');

target.addEventListener('paste', (event) => {
    let paste = (event.clipboardData || window.clipboardData).getData('text');
    paste = paste.toUpperCase();
 
    const selection = window.getSelection();
    if (!selection.rangeCount) return false;
    selection.deleteFromDocument();
    selection.getRangeAt(0).insertNode(document.createTextNode(paste));

    event.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<div class="source" contenteditable="true">Try copying text from this box...</div>
<div class="target" contenteditable="true">...and pasting it into this one</div>
```

Comment: Sadly it doesn't work in stackoverflow's search bar on google chrome.

Comment: @jeiea - What doesn't?

Comment: Unfortunately, this cannot be undone with Ctrl+z

Answer (score 2):

You can use `document.execCommand` and use `insertHTML`

```js
function handlePaste (e) {
    var clipboardData, pastedData;
    clipboardData = e.clipboardData || window.clipboardData;
    pastedData = clipboardData.getData('Text');
    e.preventDefault()
    if (pastedData.length > 10) {
         console.log("its longer", pastedData.length);
         pastedData = pastedData.substring(0, 10);
    }
    document.execCommand("insertHTML", false, pastedData);
}

document.getElementById('editableDiv').addEventListener('paste', handlePaste);
```

```html
<div id='editableDiv' contenteditable='true'>Paste</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `execCommand()` is deprecated now

Comment: don't worry. many websites still use it as it does not require additional requirements or require HTTPS secured.

Answer (score 0):

After doing the `substring(0, 10`) operation just add the content to the `div` `textContent` property, which you can access from the `event.target`:

```js
function handlePaste (event) {
    var clipboardData, pastedData;
    // Stop data actually being pasted into div
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    // Get pasted data via clipboard API
    clipboardData = event.clipboardData || window.clipboardData;
    pastedData = clipboardData.getData('Text');
    
   if(pastedData.length > 10){
     pastedData = pastedData.substring(0, 10);
   }
   event.target.textContent = pastedData;
}

document.getElementById('target').addEventListener('paste', handlePaste);
```

```html
<div id='source' contenteditable='true'>This is more than 10 characters</div>
<div id='target' contenteditable='true'>Paste here</div>
```

Comment: Note that this would replace the entire textContent in the target element.